# formsauthentication redirecttologinpage doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, redirect, authentication

I have a login.aspx. In which there is a code for redirecting page.

```
Server.Transfer(string.Format("~/admin/FillUserExtraInfo.aspx?UserName={0}",Server.UrlEncode(loginInitial.UserName)));
```

It did work, then in FillUserExtraInfo.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // retrieve the username from the querystring
        userName = this.Request.QueryString["UserName"];
        string mode = UsefulFunctions.GetOperatingMode();
        if (mode == ConfigurationSettingValues.OperatingModes.Backup.ToString())
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

However FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage() doesn't work. The program keeps executing forward until to the end of Page_Load then goes back to login eventually.

**UPDATED: During the period, I found the url bacomes `http://localhost:53906/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fLogin.aspx%3fAction%3dLogout`**

Finally. but I got an error:

```
Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.
```

My web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="default.aspx" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
    </authentication>
```

My questions:

1. Why FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage() doesn't work?
2. How to deal with the error I encountered?

Thank you.

**Second update: I added Response.End() after FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage() then it works but the exception is still there.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using Response.Redirect("url", false) rather than Server.Transfer().

```
Response.Redirect("~/admin/FillUserExtraInfo.aspx?UserName=" + Server.UrlEncode(loginInitial.UserName) + "", false);
```

[reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/EN-US/)

Comment: But I need to pass the variable "UserName" as well.

Comment: I edited my answer. please check once I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Not sure why. The page cannot be redirected. It doesn't work.

Comment: did you get any error trying that? put any valid username manually for checking Response.Redirect("~/admin/FillUserExtraInfo.aspx?UserName="uname", false);

Comment: Then threw an exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException'. Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

Comment: Hey! are you using FormsAuthentication.SignOut() for signout ?

Comment: No.Should I check HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated? it is false.